# How can we calculate renewal date of in-app subscription in android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

In my app there is two subscription one is monthly and another one is yearly,
When I purchase any subscription plan its return me a bunch of data with purchase date(in millisecond).
I want to display a purchase date which one I got it from purchase API and the other one is next renewal purchase in my app.

So how can we achieve this one?

Comment: take the purchase date milliseconds... convert to a data object... add the renewal period to it... display it ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was doing same as this one, but what the logic behind the renewal date like purchase date + 30 days for a monthly subscription plan or purchase date + 365 days for a yearly plan.

Comment: yes, that's exactly the logic behind it

Comment: Wow, thank for confirming